# Triggers to replicate Check instructions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm working on a database for a university project through XAMPP, PHPMyAdmin and MariaDB

Since as far as I understood MySQL doesn't parse `CHECK` instructions I've been trying to replicate the command with the use of a `TRIGGER` instruction, but after much searching and trying I had no luck in making it work.

The `CREATE TABLE` command is this (sorry for the italian translations)

```
CREATE TABLE Utente (
    IdU int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Mail varchar(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Nickname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Password varchar(256) NOT NULL, /*Hashed Password*/
    Nome varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Cognome varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    DataNascita date DEFAULT NULL,
    LuogoNascita varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Sesso varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    Residenza varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Categoria varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

The `CHECK` I want to replicate is this

```
CHECK (Categoria = 'Amatore' OR Categoria = 'Esperto' OR Categoria = NULL)
```

And this is the `TRIGGER` I wrote by checking some already existing threads online

```
CREATE TRIGGER V1Insert BEFORE INSERT ON Utente
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT(New.Categoria = 'Amatore' OR New.Categoria = 'Esperto' OR New.Categoria = NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10001'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT := 'Attenzione: la tupla inserita in Utente ha Categoria non valida';
    END IF;
END;
```

Ideally I'll do another trigger for the `UPDATE` command

I keep getting error `#1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':= 'Attenzione: la tupla inserita in Utente ha Categoria non valida'' at line 6`

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In the `SIGNAL` statement, `MESSAGE_TEXT` is followed by `=`, not `:=`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using MariaDB, and you're only developing your project, you can try 10.2, `CHECK` constraint has been implemented there. It is beta now, but it will most likely go GA by the time your project does.

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE Utente (
    ->     IdU int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->     Mail varchar(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    ->     Nickname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ->     Password varchar(256) NOT NULL, /*Hashed Password*/
    ->     Nome varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     Cognome varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     DataNascita date DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     LuogoNascita varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     Sesso varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     Residenza varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     Categoria varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     CHECK (Categoria = 'Amatore' OR Categoria = 'Esperto' OR Categoria IS NULL)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.55 sec)

MariaDB [test]>  INSERT INTO Utente VALUES (NULL,'foo','foo','foo','foo','foo',NULL,'foo','A','foo','foo');
ERROR 4025 (23000): CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` failed for `test`.`Utente`
MariaDB [test]>  INSERT INTO Utente VALUES (NULL,'foo','foo','foo','foo','foo',NULL,'foo','A','foo','Amatore');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [test]>  INSERT INTO Utente VALUES (NULL,'bar','foo','foo','foo','foo',NULL,'foo','A','foo',NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

But wouldn't it be easier in your case just to use `ENUM` for `Categoria`? Together with the strict mode, you'll achieve the same goal, only with a different error message:

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';

MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE Utente2 (
    ->     IdU int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->     Mail varchar(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    ->     Nickname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ->     Password varchar(256) NOT NULL, /*Hashed Password*/
    ->     Nome varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     Cognome varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     DataNascita date DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     LuogoNascita varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     Sesso varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     Residenza varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     Categoria enum ('Amatore','Esperto') NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.53 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO Utente2 VALUES (NULL,'foo','foo','foo','foo','foo',NULL,'foo','A','foo','foo');
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'Categoria' at row 1
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO Utente2 VALUES (NULL,'foo','foo','foo','foo','foo',NULL,'foo','A','foo','Amatore');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO Utente2 VALUES (NULL,'bar','foo','foo','foo','foo',NULL,'foo','A','foo',NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been thinking about using enum but read online it's not very suitable (since a wrong entry simply gives an empty string). Hopefully if the beta goes live before my project I'll definitely stick with the `CHECK` version!

Comment: Oh I just realized you wrote strict mode, I didn't even know it was a thing! If it doesn't let you insert/update a row with different values it's definitely what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` line terminator and also your this part `OR New.Categoria = NULL` should be `OR New.Categoria IS NULL`. Your trigger code should look like

```
IF (New.Categoria <> 'Amatore' OR New.Categoria <> 'Esperto' OR New.Categoria IS NOT NULL) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10001';
SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Attenzione: la tupla inserita in Utente ha Categoria non valida';
END IF;
```

Comment: The semicolon is not really required.

Comment: Thanks! The `IS NOT NULL` was definitely my mistake. I tried using your version inbetween the `BEGIN` and `END` commands but I still get `#1064` is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER V1Insert BEFORE INSERT ON Utente
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF New.Categoria NOT IN ('Amatore', 'Esperto') AND New.Categoria IS NOT NULL) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10001'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Attenzione: la tupla inserita in Utente ha Categoria non valida';
    END IF;
END;
```

Your specific problem is the `:=`.  However, you should use `IN` for comparison lists and `= NULL` is wrong.

Comment: Thank you the `= NULL` was definitely my mistake! I think it was missing a `(` after the first `IF` but I took care of that one.

Tried to parse that version but I still get `#1064`! Exactly between `'10001'` and `SET MESSAGE_TEXT`